# cv2.imread and os.listdir don't work

Tags: python, opencv

I m trying to itterate through images in a folder for further processing. 
I tried to read just one image in the folder using this code

```
import cv2  
import os 

img=cv2.imread('/home/hch/Desktop/Database/sample.jpg')
print (img.shape)

for filename in os.listdir('Database') :
    if filename.endswith(".jpg") :
        img=cv2.imread(filename)
        print (img.shape)
```

As you can see the fist part reads the image directly while the second tries to read it through `os.listdir`.

The problem is that the second part doesn't work it. it gives me this message  :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resize.py", line 10, in <module>
    print (img.shape)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

And when I print filename it prints the name of the image " sample.jpg".

Can you help me understand why it doesn't work ?

Thank you

Comment: You've failed to read the `img` so it becomes `None` hence the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that openCv is not able to open the picture.
The picture is in the directory 'Database', but your script is not triggered from there.

You are giving the wrong path.

The appropriate path would be:

```
img=cv2.imread(os.path.join('Database',filename))
```